# IllegalStateException: No Activity when navigating back from Activity

Tags: android, webview, navigation

I have a simple `Activity` that holds a `WebView` with the following code:

```
class AppInfo : BaseActivity() {

    override fun inject() {
        App.appInstance().appComponent().inject(this)
    }

    companion object {
        const val INFO = "info"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.webview)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        val infoToLoad = intent.getStringExtra(INFO)

        supportActionBar?.title = infoToLoad

        Timber.i(infoToLoad)

        webView?.scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY
        webView?.webViewClient = CustomWebViewClient()
        webView?.loadUrl(
                if (infoToLoad == Constants.TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS)
                    Constants.TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS_URL
                else
                    Constants.PRIVACY_POLICY_URL
        )
    }

    private inner class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(request!!.url.toString())
            return true
        }

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            view.loadUrl(url)
            return true
        }


    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        return when (item?.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                onBackPressed()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Attempting to navigate back from the actionbar arrow or the device back button yields the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
                              at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1621)
                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMoveToState(FragmentManager.java:3046)
                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3003)
                              at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:193)
                               at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7159)
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949)
                              at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:194)
                              at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
                               at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:157)
                               at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:72)
                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
```

This is the activity I want to navigate back to:

```
class PreferenceActivity : AppCompatActivity(), GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private var googleApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null
    private var analyticsUtil: AnalyticsUtil? = null

    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.preference_activity)

        analyticsUtil = AnalyticsUtil(this)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.title = resources.getString(R.string.settings)

        val googleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .build()

        googleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
                .build()

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.contentFrame, SettingsFragment())
                .commitAllowingStateLoss()

        analyticsUtil?.recordScreenView("Settings")
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                FlurryAgent.endTimedEvent("Settings")

                finish()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    private fun logoutFromGoogle() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).setResultCallback { deleteUser() }
    }

    private fun logoutFromFacebook() {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()

        deleteUser()
    }

    //TODO stop player on log out
    private fun deleteUser() {
        try {
            startService(Intent(this, MusicPlaybackService::class.java).setAction(MediaTasks.ACTION_STOP))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e)
        }

        PrefUtils.putBoolean(PrefUtils.LOGIN_STATUS, false)

        PrefUtils.remove(Constants.USER)

        startActivity(Intent(this, SplashPage::class.java).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
    }

    override fun onConnectionFailed(connectionResult: ConnectionResult) {
        Timber.d("onConnectionFailed:$connectionResult")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        ActivityRecreationHelper.onDestroy(this)
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        finish()
    }

    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragment() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)

            val manager = activity.packageManager
            var info: PackageInfo? = null
            try {
                info = manager.getPackageInfo(activity.packageName, 0)
            } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
                Timber.e(e, e.localizedMessage)
            }

            val version = buildString {
                append(info?.versionName)
                append("(")
                append(info?.versionCode)
                append(")")
            }

            val versionPreference = findPreference(VERSION)
            versionPreference.summary = version

            val userPreference = findPreference(LOGOUT)

            if (Songa.getRAGUser() != null)
                userPreference.summary = "You are logged in as " + Songa.getRAGUser()!!.user.name

            userPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener {
                try {
                    (activity as PreferenceActivity).logoutFromGoogle()
                    (activity as PreferenceActivity).logoutFromFacebook()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Timber.e(e.message)
                }
                true
            }

            val termsPreference = findPreference(TERMS)
            termsPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener {
                if (NetworkHelper.isOnline(activity as AppCompatActivity))
                    startActivity<AppInfo>(AppInfo.INFO to Constants.TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS)
                else
                    toast(getString(R.string.network_error))
                true
            }

            val privacyPreference = findPreference(PRIVACY)
            privacyPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener {
                if (NetworkHelper.isOnline(activity as AppCompatActivity))
                    startActivity<AppInfo>(AppInfo.INFO to Constants.PRIVACY_POLICY)
                else
                    toast(getString(R.string.network_error))
                true
            }

            val languagePreference = findPreference(LANGUAGE) as ListPreference
            languagePreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener { _, value ->
                when (value as String) {
                    "en" -> LocaleChanger.setLocale(Songa.SUPPORTED_LOCALES[0])
                    "sw-rKE" -> LocaleChanger.setLocale(Songa.SUPPORTED_LOCALES[1])
                    "sw-rTZ" -> LocaleChanger.setLocale(Songa.SUPPORTED_LOCALES[2])
                }

                ActivityRecreationHelper.recreate(activity, true)
                true
            }

            val themePreference = findPreference(THEME) as SwitchPreference
            themePreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener { _, value ->
                val isEnabled = value as Boolean

                PrefUtils.putBoolean(PrefUtils.NIGHT_MODE, isEnabled)
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(if (isEnabled) AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES else AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)

                startActivity<Home>(Home.RESTART to true) //send flag to activity to ensure it's recreated to effect theme change and not just brought to front
                true
            }

            val feedbackPreference = findPreference(FEEDBACK)
            feedbackPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener {
                startActivity<FeedbackActivity>()
                true
            }

            val profilePreference = findPreference(PROFILE)
            profilePreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener {
                startActivity<SubscriptionDetails>()
                true
            }
        }

        companion object {

            private const val VERSION = "app_version"
            private const val LOGOUT = "logout"
            private const val TERMS = "terms_and_conditions"
            private const val PRIVACY = "privacy_policy"
            private const val LANGUAGE = "language"
            private const val FEEDBACK = "feedback"
            private const val PROFILE = "profile"
            const val THEME = "theme"
        }
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase))
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you performing some actions in `onResume` method in `Activity` or `Fragment` where you suppose to return back?

Comment: @Yupi no. The previous activity is just a `SettingsActivity` with a `PreferenceFragment`.

Comment: try using finish() instead of onBackPressed()

Comment: @AlexKombo do you have nested `Fragments`?

Comment: @Yupi no, please check updated question for the `PreferenceActivity`.

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy I tried that too but it didn't work.

Comment: I have the same preference activity setup, i am using getSupportFragmentManager() while attaching the fragment, also my fragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy I haven't actually tried the `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, let me give it a try.

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy I've switched to `PreferenceFragmentCompat` but the error is still persistent.